# CSS Push Div to bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I want the footer to always be at the bottom of the page even if the content doesn't push it all the way down. How can I make it just stay at the bottom of the page?

Comment: See [CSS Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) or [New CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/).

Comment: New CSS Sticky Footer worked well for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make div stay at bottom of page's content all the time even when there are scrollbars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824831/make-div-stay-at-bottom-of-pages-content-all-the-time-even-when-there-are-scrol)

Answer (score 33):

```
 #footer { position: fixed; bottom: 0; }
```

Comment: Note this is for a footer with ID="footer", to target the footer element omit the #

Comment: -1. This does not position the element at the bottom of the page, it positions it at the bottom of the screen.  Those are very different requests.

Answer (score 2):

If you always want it to be at the bottom of the visible page even when the content pushes down further than the viewable area try absolutely positioning the div and adding a margin to the bottom of your page.