# Make div stay at bottom of page's content all the time even when there are scrollbars

Tags: css, positioning, css-position, footer

I am looking to implement the opposite behaviour to the following question: [CSS Push Div to bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140763/css-push-div-to-bottom-of-page). I.e., when content overflows to the scrollbars, I would like the footer to be at the bottom of the page, like Stack Overflow.

I have a div with `id="footer"` and the following CSS:

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This moves the div to the bottom of the viewport - but the element stays there even when you scroll the page down, so it is no longer at the bottom.

How can I make sure the div stays at the bottom of the page's contents even when the content overflows? I'm not looking for fixed positioning, only for the element to be at the bottom of all content.

Image: [image: Example]

Comment: try `position:fixed` , though that won't be exactly the best way to do it

Comment: Try position: relative on body.

Comment: you didn't close your ; after position: absolute. 

it would have worked perfectly otherwise!

Answer (score 695, accepted):

This is precisely what `position: fixed` was designed for:

```css
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uw8f9/

Comment: That solution is not good for 90% of cases. if you re-size your window, your footer will overlay other content and won't stop right at the end of your content

Comment: @aroth that is because they are two totally different solutions. This solution will keep the footer at the bottom of the visual area of the screen at all times. The alternative solution keeps the footer at either the bottom of the screen or the bottom of the page, depending on which is larger - which was what the asker requested.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts - You're absolutely right. After answering, I realized that this was not what the OP wanted, but I left it here for people looking for a simple fixed footer. From the comments (and votes) it seems many people are struggling with this elementary CSS feature.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts - Fair enough, though for my money they're both still basically the same.  Content scrolls underneath the `fixed` footer, when there is enough content to do so.  That's good enough for me.  Of course, I can see how *very large* footers like what they have on stackoverflow would not work well with the `fixed` approach, but for a basic one-line footer this approach works well in my opinion.

Comment: @aroth I agree, this is a good solution and it all depends what you want. I was just pointing out why one solution was more complicated than the other -> they don't do the same thing.

Comment: This is a solution for a "fixed" footer, not a "sticky" footer.

Comment: @rob - Correct. Read the comments above yours.

Answer (score 215):

Unfortunately, you can't do this without adding a little extra HTML and having one piece of CSS rely on another.

**HTML**

First, you need to wrap your `header`,`footer` and `#body` into a `#holder` div:

```
<div id="holder">
    <header>.....</header>
    <div id="body">....</div>
    <footer>....</footer>
</div>
```

**CSS**

Then set `height: 100%` to `html` and `body` (actual body, not your `#body` div) to ensure you can set minimum height as a percentage on child elements.

Now set `min-height: 100%` on the `#holder` div so it fills the content of the screen and uses `position: absolute` to sit the footer at the bottom of the `#holder` div.

Unfortunately, you have to apply `padding-bottom` to the `#body` div that is the same height as the `footer` to ensure that the `footer` does not sit above any content:

```
html,body{
    height: 100%
}

#holder{
    min-height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

#body{
    padding-bottom: 100px;    /* height of footer */
}

footer{
    height: 100px; 
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
}
```

**Working example, short body: http://jsfiddle.net/ELUGc/**

**Working example, long body: http://jsfiddle.net/ELUGc/1/**

If you are having problems in asp.net, you need to add 'height : 100%' to the main generated FORM tag as well as HTML and BODY tags for this to work.

Comment: @sTACKoVERFLOW - If you do not specify a `width` **or both** `left` and `right` then the values are set to `auto` and the element will wrap to fit its content. Specifying `width: 100%` **or** `left: 0` and `right:0` ensures that the absolutely positioned element takes the full width of the container element

Comment: I was looking for similar behavior, but in my case the #body div is floated, by say "float: left". The short body example works, but the long body example does not. Any suggestions how I can get the desired behavior using float on the #body div.

Comment: @Ian said, in an answer because he didn't have enough rep to comment:If you are having problems in asp.net with the answer from 'My Head Hurts' - you need to add 'height : 100%' to the main generated FORM tag as well as HTML and BODY tags in order for this to work.

Comment: If you're trying to get this to work inside a div rather than inside the whole body, make sure you specify `height=100%` on _all_ of your containing elements, including `<form>` elements.

Comment: the main point you did that he didnt was close your position: fixed with a ;

Comment: I still don't get why all this boilerplate is needed, but it was indeed the only way that prevented my footer from moving out of place or covering other content for any window size, when combined with this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12408519

Answer (score 19):

Just worked out for another solution as above example have bug( somewhere error ) for me. Variation from the selected answer.

```
html,body {
    height: 100%
}

#nonFooter {
    min-height: 100%;
    position:relative;
    /* Firefox */
    min-height: -moz-calc(100% - 30px);
    /* WebKit */
    min-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 30px);
    /* Opera */
    min-height: -o-calc(100% - 30px);
    /* Standard */
    min-height: calc(100% - 30px);
}

#footer {
    height:30px;
    margin: 0;
    clear: both;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

for html layout

```
<body>
    <div id="nonFooter">header,middle,left,right,etc</div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Well this way don't support old browser however its acceptable for old browser to scrolldown 30px to view the footer

- [plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/7g4T7ujxOYUqpL8i?open=index.html&preview)

Answer (score 7):

You didn't close your ; after position: absolute.
Otherwise your above code would have worked perfectly!

```
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:30px;
   width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would comment if i could , but i have no permissions yet, so i will post a hint as an answer, for unexpected behavior on some android devices:

Position: Fixed only works in Android 2.1 thru 2.3 by using the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">.
```

see http://caniuse.com/#search=position

Answer (score 2):

This is an intuitive solution using the viewport command that just sets the minimum height to the viewport height minus the footer height.

```
html,body{
height: 100%
}
#nonFooter{
min-height: calc(100vh - 30px)
}

#footer {
height:30px;
margin: 0;
clear: both;
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
(if needs element in whole display and left align)
left:0;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer

Answer (score 1):

I've solved a similar issue by putting all of my main content within an extra div tag (id="outer").  I've then moved the div tag with id="footer" outside of this last "outer" div tag.
I've used CSS to specify the height of "outer" and specified the width and height of "footer".  I've also used CSS to specify the margin-left and margin-right of "footer" as auto.  The result is that the footer sits firmly at the bottom of my page and scrolls with the page too (although, it's still appears inside the "outer" div, but happily outside of the main "content" div. which seems strange, but it's where I want it).

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add - most of the other answers worked fine for me; however, it took a long time to get them working!

This is because setting `height: 100%` only picks up parent div's height!

So if your entire html (inside of the body) looks like the following:

```
<div id="holder">
    <header>.....</header>
    <div id="body">....</div>
    <footer>....</footer>
</div>
```

Then the following will be fine:

```
html,body{
    height: 100%
}

#holder{
    min-height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

#body{
    padding-bottom: 100px;    /* height of footer */
}

footer{
    height: 100px; 
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
}
```

...as "holder" will pick up it's height directly from "body".

*Kudos to My Head Hurts, whose answer was the one I ended up getting to work!*

**However.** If your html is more nested (because it's only an element of the full page, or it's within a certain column, etc) then you need to make sure *every containing element* also has `height: 100%` set on the div. Otherwise, the information on height will be lost between "body" and "holder".

E.g. the following, where I've added the "full height" class to every div to make sure the height gets all the way down to our header/body/footer elements:

```
<div class="full-height">
    <div class="container full-height">
        <div id="holder">
            <header>.....</header>
            <div id="body">....</div>
            <footer>....</footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And remember to set height on full-height class in the css:

```
#full-height{
    height: 100%;
}
```

That fixed my issues!

Answer (score 0):

if you have a fixed height footer (for example 712px) you can do this with js like so:

```
var bgTop = 0;
window.addEventListener("resize",theResize);
function theResize(){
    bgTop = winHeight - 712;
    document.getElementById("bg").style.marginTop = bgTop+"px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit my footer with a margin-top: auto and it did the trick! Im commenting this here just in case it could help any future visitors.

Comment: Could you share you code ?

Comment: I used it [here](https://github.com/Milkdromeda-333/makeup-market/blob/main/src/components/Layout.jsx), but i can make a little mini project to show you a tangible example if you'd like.