# CSS - Content with 100% min-height creates a vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css, height, scrollbar

I'm trying to create a page with a header with a navigation menu and a content area that fills the rest of the page, the content have a 100% min-height but even when it's empty it shows a vertical scrollbar because of the header size.

HTML relevant part:

```
<body>
  <div id="header">Davi Andrade</div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Downloads</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="content">
    Text
  </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
html, body {
  background: #333333;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  color: #b6b6b6;
  float: left;
  font-family: Megrim;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 18px 52px 18px 52px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 18, 255, 0.8), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav li a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 24px 48px 24px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#content {
  clear: both;
  background: #3e3e3e;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.35), 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

There is any way to fix this?

Comment: It looks fine to me in Chrome and FF... Do you mean that the lighter grey area below has its own scrollbar or are you saying the content area is too large thus producing the normal scrollbar?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-screen-space

Comment: The content area is too large, it should show a scrollbar only when needed..

Comment: You must write some Javascript... I don't sure that it's possible with CSS.

Comment: I don't know javascript, are you sure this is the only way?

Comment: I would just change the body background to be the color you need and allow the content div to grow as needed.  The effect should be the same.

Comment: It is possible with pure CSS and there are many of answers. The main question is though - do you actually need the div to the fill the screen, for example you need a footer to be at the bottom, or as @Mark says; can you not just set the color of the background on the body instead of that div?

Comment: I'll need a footer. I can change the header color and make the body gray but I wanted to make the pages animated like that: http://iiro.eu/index.html

Comment: Unfortunately the guy in the example has it easier than you do thanks to his side by side layout. However, here is an answer I gave the other day to someone with a similar question to this one (no slide effect I'm afraid but I would think it is still perfectly possible): http://stackoverflow.com/a/8825714/681807

Comment: I tried what you said, but it ended up like this: http://cl.ly/2R3r2A0o2i1Y3m092m0P Any ideas?

Comment: You need to assign the colour of the `#content` to the `body` tag. [Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AqJp2/), I have changed your HTML slightly to make it a little more semantic. Let me know if you have any questions about it.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! One more question, how this "overflow: hidden" works?

Comment: No problem - if you want me to add it as answer to this question then let me know, otherwise just stick an upvote on the answer I linked you too. The `overflow: hidden` is a way of clearing the floats from child elements.

Comment: I can't vote up because I don't have enough reputation, feel free to post an answer ;)

Comment: Ok, I have added the answer. Don't forget to accept ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, this layout can be achieved in one of two ways.

Firstly, if you do not need anything at the foot of the page then you should just remove `min-height` and `background-color` off `#content` and place the `background-color` in the `body` instead. I would also change the header HTML structure slightly to make it a little more semantically correct and easier to work with:

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>Davi Andrade</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Downloads</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="content">
    ....
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* change original #header to h1 and add the following CSS */
#header {
    background: #333333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* remove back ground color from #content and add here */
html, body {
    ....
    background-color: #3e3e3e;
    ....
}
```

Secondly, if you do need a footer at the bottom of the page then you will need to make the changes above and then wrap your HTML inside a container element with `min-height: 100%`. You can then use `position: absolute` to place the  footer element at the bottom of the container element. There are a few other bits and pieces to it which I have explained in more detail within [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8825714/681807).

**With footer: http://jsfiddle.net/cNfWZ/1/**

**Without footer: http://jsfiddle.net/cNfWZ/**

Comment: Not that it would make a huge difference, but you mixed up your two links.
Nice answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Yea. Lose the min-height property.

Comment: But if I do this the content area will not fill the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

[Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-screen-space)

This really isn't all that possible using normal CSS and HTML.

If all you want is for the background to be that lighter gray, I would suggest that you make the background of the body be that color and then make the header and nav be the darker grey. The content will look like it fills the rest, but won't actually.

Edit:

Sorry, I should say not possible using a div and the body element. With a table you can achieve something like what you are going for.

Comment: I though about inverting the colors, but I wanted to make the content part animated so it needed to be the one with the shadow. It would be a bad idea to use a table?

Comment: @SimpleTouch there is no need to bring tables into this. Just because you don't know how to do it using `div` elements does not mean it is not possible.

Comment: Not at all. Tables tend to be looked down upon cause of a bad history of being overused and are more HTML markup than is typically needed for a given task, but if they do the job nothing else can without hacks, I see no reason not to.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Definitely agreed. I normally avoid tables like the plague. There are a few answers in the SO question I referenced that claim to accomplish this without a table, which should definitely be explored. I'm just not sure how well they will fit with what Davi is trying to do with his layout.

Comment: The table worked perfectly, but I'll test the other solutions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Steve Sanderson has a great treatment of height CSS issues here: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/10/05/full-height-app-layouts-a-css-trick-to-make-it-easier/

Comment: Interesting, but I don't see how this can help in my case.