# Sticky Footer in HTML5 Boilerplate

Tags: css, sticky-footer, boilerplate, html5boilerplate

I am trying to implement a sticky footer in boilerplate but I can't find a way for this to work. I have tried solutions posted by [Michael Gorman](http://www.michaelcgorman.net/2011/01/06/css-sticky-footers/) and [Steve Hatcher](http://www.smipple.net/snippet/Owlyfool/HTML5%20Boilerplate%20Sticky%20Footer%20With%20100%25%20wide%20centered%20header/footer%20CSS) but both do not work for me.

I have researched and found that Sticky Footer is not supported by Boilerplate. Have any of you had any luck with this issue.

To see a page where I really need a sticky footer, please go [here](http://clintongreen.com/clients/researchreview/thankyou.html)

Thanks for helping. Cheers

Comment: Is this the kind of thing that you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8825714/681807?

Comment: This works great, I just had to add a negative margin-top to the footer to prevent an overlap in long pages. Thanks, please add this as an answer and I'll accept. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ensure that the footer is always at the absolute bottom of the page you can use the answer accepted in this question: [Make div stay at bottom of page's content all the time even when there are scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8824831/681807)

You will prob find that it requires a little fine tuning to work exactly as you require for your design.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a piece of HTML that stays on the same position of the screen regardless of the scrolling, you can use `position:fixed` on the element. This will create an effect similar to what you see on facebook, where the blue bar at the top, and the chat window at the bottom stay visible.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a traditional Sticky footer because I don't want the footer to be fixed. Cheers