# Can't get the container to expand according to its content

Tags: html, css, footer

I did try a few suggestions that I found online but none of them worked. I tried to [fix the footer at the bottom using Flexbox layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41401759/content-goes-past-footer) but it didn't work, when I add more cards they overflow and go past the footer. I also followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537838/div-height-100-and-expands-to-fit-content/17807687#17807687) and added the two properties to my main page, but the problem is `card-container` does not expand to fit the content (it display has to `flex`) and only the main div (for whole page) does.

Do you have any suggestions or workarounds for this issue?

```css
/* RESET */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #ebecf0;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
body a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #172b4d;
}
body h1 {
  font-family: "Song Myung", serif;
}
/* DEFAULT STYLE */
:root {
  font-size: 16px;
  --card-img-height: 200px;
}
.card-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.card {
  align-self: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  width: 325px;
  min-width: 275px;
  margin: 1.25rem 0.75rem;
  background: white;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.card .card-img {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--card-img-height);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.card .card-img-hovered {
  --card-img-hovered-overlay: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: var(--card-img-height);
  top: 0;
}
.card .card-info {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.card .card-info .card-about {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.75rem 0;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.card .card-info .card-about .card-tag {
  width: 60px;
  max-width: 100px;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: #505f79;
  color: #fff;
}
.card .card-info .card-about .card-tag.tag-news {
  background: #36b37e;
}
.card .card-info .card-about .card-tag.tag-deals {
  background: #ffab00;
}
.card .card-info .card-about .card-tag.tag-politics {
  width: 71px;
  background: #ff5630;
}
.card .card-info .card-title {
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
  transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
}
.card .card-info .card-creator {
  padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.card:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 35px rgba(227, 252, 239, 0.1), 0px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  transform: scale(1.025);
}
.card:hover .card-img-hovered {
  --card-img-hovered-overlay: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65));
  height: 100%;
}
.card:hover .card-about, .card:hover .card-creator {
  opacity: 0;
}
.card:hover .card-info {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.card:hover .card-title {
  color: #ebecf0;
  transform: translate(0, 40px);
}
.card-1 .card-img, .card-1 .card-img-hovered {
  background-image: var(--card-img-hovered-overlay), url(https://source.unsplash.com/Qm_n6aoYzDs);
}
.card-2 .card-img, .card-2 .card-img-hovered {
  background-image: var(--card-img-hovered-overlay), url(https://source.unsplash.com/C-v1p2DTakA);
}
.card-3 .card-img, .card-3 .card-img-hovered {
  background-image: var(--card-img-hovered-overlay), url(https://source.unsplash.com/V0L1LH7qWOQ);
}
.card-4 .card-img, .card-4 .card-img-hovered {
  background-image: var(--card-img-hovered-overlay), url(https://source.unsplash.com/zAi2Is48-MA);
}


.page-footer{
  height: 3rem;
  background: #cddc39;
  color: var(--primary-900);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: var(--letterSpacing);
}

.page-footer p{
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;

}

.footer-logo, .page-footer a{
  color: #0f5132;

}

.columned-footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-inline-start: 0.1rem;
  background-color: rgb(70, 66, 66);
  height: 8rem;
  color: rgb(243, 240, 235);
  width: 100%;
}

.social {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgb(70, 66, 66);
  height: 5rem;
  border-top: 0.1rem solid;
  border-top-color: rgb(102, 99, 99);
}

.social_footer_ul { 
  display:table;
  margin:10px auto 0 auto;
  list-style-type:none; 
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.social_footer_ul li { 
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left:20px; 
  float:left; 
}

.social_footer_ul li a { 
  padding:15px;
  color: #e2e0ff;

}

.social_footer_ul li a:hover { 
  opacity: 0.2px;
  color: #cddc39;
}

.social_footer_ul li i {  
  width:20px; 
  height:20px; 
  text-align:center;
}

.footer-container {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    display: grid;
    gap: 10rem;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    padding-inline-start: 2rem;
}

.line {
  height: 2px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: #cddc39;
  margin: 3px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.streak {
  height:2px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #acb930;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 50px;
  padding: 1px;
}

.address {
  float: right;
}

.tel {
  float: left;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 748px) {
  .footer-container{
   width: 100%;
   padding-inline-start: 5rem;
  }
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
body > *{
  flex-grow: 0;
}
body > nav + .card-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card card-1">
    <div class="card-img"></div>
    <a href="" class="card-link">
      <div class="card-img-hovered"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="card-info">
      <div class="card-about">
        <a class="card-tag tag-news">NEWS</a>
      <div class="card-time">6/11/2018</div>
      </div>
      <h1 class="card-title">There have been big Tesla accident at New Jersey</h1>
      <div class="card-creator">by <a href="">Sardorbek Usmonov</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-2">
    <div class="card-img"></div>
    <a href="" class="card-link">
      <div class="card-img-hovered"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="card-info">
      <div class="card-about">
        <a class="card-tag">Tech</a>
      <div class="card-time">6/07/2018</div>
      </div>
      <h1 class="card-title">Samsung laptops is exploding again</h1>
      <div class="card-creator">by <a href="">Tyler Platt</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-3">
    <div class="card-img"></div>
    <a href="" class="card-link">
      <div class="card-img-hovered"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="card-info">
      <div class="card-about">
        <a class="card-tag tag-deals">Deals</a>
      <div class="card-time">5/27/2018</div>
      </div>
      <h1 class="card-title">Apple is having big Sale for the first time</h1>
      <div class="card-creator">by <a href="">Timur Mirzoyev</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-4">
    <div class="card-img"></div>
    <a href="" class="card-link">
      <div class="card-img-hovered"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="card-info">
      <div class="card-about">
        <a class="card-tag tag-politics">Politics</a>
      <div class="card-time">5/20/2018</div>
      </div>
      <h1 class="card-title">Net-Nutrality is coming to its end</h1>
      <div class="card-creator">by <a href="">Gregoy Trem</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>


   <footer>
    
     <div class="social">
     <ul class="social_footer_ul">
       <li><a href="http://facebook.com"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="http://twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="http://telegram.com"><i class="fab fa-telegram"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="http://instagram.com"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
    <div class="page-footer">
    <p>
        &copy; <span id="date"></span>
        <span class="footer-logo"></span>
       by me  <a href=""></a>
    </p>
   </div>
  </footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.card-container` needs `min-height: 100vh;` instead of `height: 100vh;`