# Twitter Bootstrap - Making footer run full width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my footer run the whole width of the web page like the navigation, however I want to centre the content of the footer inline with the content above.

```
<footer>
    <div class="container narrow">
       <div class="row-fluid footer">
          <div class="span4">
          </div>
          <div class="span3">
          </div>
          <div class="span5">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

I thought that adding the classes `<div class="container narrow">` inside the footer would centre the content but this has not worked. Any ideas?

The site is available here - http://www.openreachmarketing.co.uk/

Comment: putting  different span's in your footer isn't going to allow it to run the whole width, i'd presume if you'll need something like 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824831/make-div-stay-at-bottom-of-pages-content-all-the-time-even-when-there-are-scrol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the footer background defined in the `.footer` class. So you need `.footer` to wrap around `.container.narrow`.

This works when I try:

```
<footer>
    <div class="footer">
       <div class="container narrow row-fluid">
          <div class="span4">
          </div>
          <div class="span3">
          </div>
          <div class="span5">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: <footer><div class="container"> your content </div></footer>