# Full-width div on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this blue top [link here](http://textarea-teste.aws.af.cm/) and this top is taking all width size, and that's what I want. So if you resize your window or open it on mobile this blue div is putting margins both sides, twitter bootstrap responsive is doing that. My code is exactly like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838482/twitter-bootstrap-making-footer-run-full-width) but tb still putting margins, that's my code:

```
<!-- this div is inserting blue bg image and wrap all content -->
<div class="background-top"> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="span6"></div>
        <div class="span6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a similar media query to target the top background div as its Bootstrap that seems to be adding the body padding. Give this a go:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .background-top {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
  }
}
```