# Positioning Footer at the Bottom of Website Page

Tags: html, css, position

I'm trying to make this template, which I'm going to later be converting into a WordPress theme. The problem I'm having is similar to this post: [Make div stay at bottom of page's content all the time even when there are scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824831/make-div-stay-at-bottom-of-pages-content-all-the-time-even-when-there-are-scrol) But when I tried the solutions off of that post, but didn't work for me.

What I want to have is the footer be at the very bottom of the page (hidden from view if the content is longer than the viewer's browser window) and not have it fixed on the bottom of the window.

All of the top content (the navigation, bars, logo, etc.) is positioned where I would like it to be. But the link above the footer and the footer aren't positioned at the very bottom of the page. Instead, when it first loads up, it positions itself at the bottom of the page. The more content it has, it stays in the area where it first loaded. See the screenshot below:
[image: footer stuck in the middle]

Here is the following HTML/CSS for the page:

**HTML**

```
<div id="blackbar"></div>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="redbar">
        <img src="images/logo_broeren_03.png" alt="" title="" />
        </div>

        <div id="navigationWrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="whitebar">
                <img src="images/logo_broeren_04.png" alt="" title="" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="newsbar">
        </div>

        <div id="contentWrapper">

            <div id="secondaryNavigation">
            </div>

            <div id="slider-headline">
            </div>

            <div id="content">
                <div class="post">
                    <p>Contains post content</p>
                 </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>



    <div id="footer">
    <span id="studioLink">designed by Two Eleven Studios</span>
        <ul>
            <li>602 N. Country Fair Drive, P.O. Box 6537 &#8226; Champaign, Illinois 61826&#8211;6537</li>
            <li>217&#8211;352&#8211;4232</li>
            <li>example@broerenrusso.com</li>
            <li>&copy; 2012 Broeren Russo Inc.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
/*General Implementations*/
body {
    background: #6CF;   
    width: 100%;
}

/*Main Elements*/
/*Black bar on the far left side*/
#blackbar {
        background: #000;
        height: 55px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25px;
        /*width: 155px;*/
        width: 15%;
    }

/*Red bar containing red part image of logo*/
#redbar {
    background: #C0272D;
    width: 114px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
}
#redbar img {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 24px;
}

/*Wrapper containing main content, navigation,  white bar w/ logo, news feed, and main content*/
#wrapper {
    width: 798px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 15%;
    /*left: 155px;*/
}

/*Navigation wrapper containing white bar w/ logo and main navigation*/
#navigationWrapper {
    width: 570px;
    height: 130px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'RobotoLight', Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*Main navigation settings*/
#navigationWrapper ul {
    /*position: relative;
    top: 0;
    float: right;*/
    height: 24px;
    width: 570px;
}
#navigationWrapper ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 114px;
    /*height: 22px;*/
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    padding: 3px 0 0 0;
}
#navigationWrapper ul li:hover { 
    border-top: 2px #C0272D solid;
    padding: 1px 0 0 0;
}
#navigationWrapper ul li a { 
    position: relative; 
    top: 10px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*White bar w/ white logo*/
#whitebar {
    background: #FFF;
    height: 56px;
    width: 570px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}
#whitebar img { 
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}

/*News feed on the side*/
#newsbar {
    width: 114px;
    height: 179px;
    background: #FFF;
    margin: 80px 0 0 0;
}

/*Slider/Headline Block and content block*/
#slider-headline, #content {
    width: 684px;
}
/*Slider/Headline Block*/
#slider-headline { 
    background: #000; 
    height: 302px;
}
/*content block*/
#content { 
    background: #FFF; 
    padding: 6.5em 0 1em 0;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
}
/*wrapper containing slider/headline block and content block*/
#contentWrapper {
    width: 684px;
    margin: -179px 0 24px 114px;    
}

/*Company tagline (only on index page)*/
#companyTagline {
    float: right;
    font-family: 'RobotoMedium', Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Secondary navigation within contentWrapper*/
#secondaryNavigation {
    width: 611px;
    height: 110px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute; 
    background: #666;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 320px;
    right: 44px;
}

/*Post settings*/
.post {
    width: 89%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*Studio link*/
#studioLink {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 27px;
    left: 3px;
    font: 8px 'RobotoLight', Arial, sans-serif;
}

/*Main footer*/
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #CCC;
    height: 24px;
}
#footer ul {
    width: 684px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#footer ul li {
    list-style-image: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font: 9px/11px 'RobotoLight', Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 23px 0 0;
}
#footer ul li:last { margin: 0; }
```

I know part of the problem is all of the top content (navigation, white bar on top, etc.) have the `position: absolute;` CSS within them. But I wanted to keep this CSS declaration. How do I have it so the link above the footer and the footer itself positioned at the bottom of the page/content and not positioned at the bottom of the window?

Comment: Try to change the `footer ul{width:684px;}` to `footer ul{width:100%;}`

Comment: whenever I have to play with footer this is the first place I go..http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: @Vucko The reason I had `footer ul` set to `width: 684px` was because I wanted to have that area move along with the main content of the page. In order for this to happen, a width needs to be defined.

Comment: @Scorpio I checked out the page in your comment and isn't exactly what I want. What I want is for the footer to be at the bottom of the page, not always visible in the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here it is. It took a long time because of absolute positioning

```
<body>
<div style="width:100%; min-height: 100%; position: relative; display:inline-block;">
    <div id="blackbar">
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="redbar">
            <img src="images/logo_broeren_03.png" alt="" title="" />
        </div>
        <div id="navigationWrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="whitebar">
                <img src="images/logo_broeren_04.png" alt="" title="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="newsbar">
        </div>
        <div id="contentWrapper">
            <div id="secondaryNavigation">
            </div>
            <div id="slider-headline">
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <div class="post">
                    <p>
                        Contains post content</p>
                    <br />
                    <p>
                        Contains post content</p>
                    <br />
                    <p>
                        Contains post content</p>
                    <br />
                    <p>
                        Contains post content</p>
                    <br />
                    <p>
                        Contains post content</p>
                    <br />
                    <p>
                        Contains post content</p>
                    <br />
                    <p>
                        Contains post content</p>
                    <br />
                    <p>
                        Contains post content</p>
                    <br />
                    <p>
                        Contains post content</p>
                    <br />
                    <p>
                        Contains post content</p>
                    <br />
                    <p>
                        Contains post content</p>
                    <br />
                    <p>
                        Contains post content</p>
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <span id="studioLink">designed by Two Eleven Studios</span>
        <ul>
            <li>602 N. Country Fair Drive, P.O. Box 6537  Champaign, Illinois 618266537</li>
            <li>2173524232</li>
            <li>example@broerenrusso.com</li>
            <li> 2012 Broeren Russo Inc.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
 </body>
```

​
css

```
  <style type="text/css">
    /*General Implementations*/
    html, body
    {
        background: #6CF;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    /*Main Elements*/
    /*Black bar on the far left side*/
    #blackbar
    {
        background: #000;
        height: 55px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25px; /*width: 155px;*/
        width: 15%;
    }

    /*Red bar containing red part image of logo*/
    #redbar
    {
        background: #C0272D;
        width: 114px;
        height: 80px;
        float: left;
    }
    #redbar img
    {
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        top: 24px;
    }

    /*Wrapper containing main content, navigation,  white bar w/ logo, news feed, and main content*/
    #wrapper
    {
        width: 798px;
        min-height: 100%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        left: 15%; /*left: 155px;*/
    }

    /*Navigation wrapper containing white bar w/ logo and main navigation*/
    #navigationWrapper
    {
        width: 570px;
        height: 130px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        float: left;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: 'RobotoLight' , Arial, sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    /*Main navigation settings*/
    #navigationWrapper ul
    {
        /*position: relative;
top: 0;
float: right;*/
        height: 24px;
        width: 570px;
    }
    #navigationWrapper ul li
    {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 114px; /*height: 22px;*/
        text-align: right;
        float: right;
        padding: 3px 0 0 0;
    }
    #navigationWrapper ul li:hover
    {
        border-top: 2px #C0272D solid;
        padding: 1px 0 0 0;
    }
    #navigationWrapper ul li a
    {
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    /*White bar w/ white logo*/
    #whitebar
    {
        background: #FFF;
        height: 56px;
        width: 570px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
    }
    #whitebar img
    {
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
    }

    /*News feed on the side*/
    #newsbar
    {
        width: 114px;
        height: 179px;
        background: #FFF;
        margin: 80px 0 0 0;
    }

    /*Slider/Headline Block and content block*/
    #slider-headline, #content
    {
        width: 684px;
    }
    /*Slider/Headline Block*/
    #slider-headline
    {
        background: #000;
        height: 302px;
    }
    /*content block*/
    #content
    {
        background: #FFF;
        padding: 6.5em 0 1em 0;
        margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
    }
    /*wrapper containing slider/headline block and content block*/
    #contentWrapper
    {
        width: 684px;
        margin: -179px 0 24px 114px;
    }

    /*Company tagline (only on index page)*/
    #companyTagline
    {
        float: right;
        font-family: 'RobotoMedium' , Arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    }

    /*Secondary navigation within contentWrapper*/
    #secondaryNavigation
    {
        width: 611px;
        height: 110px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: absolute;
        background: #666;
        z-index: 10;
        top: 320px;
        right: 44px;
    }

    /*Post settings*/
    .post
    {
        width: 89%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    /*Studio link*/
    #studioLink
    {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 27px;
        left: 3px;
        font: 8px 'RobotoLight' , Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    /*Main footer*/
    #footer
    {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #CCC;
        height: 24px;
    }
    #footer ul
    {
        width: 684px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #footer ul li
    {
        list-style-image: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font: 9px/11px 'RobotoLight' , Arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 0 23px 0 0;
    }
    #footer ul li:last
    {
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Z5qj/). Working perfect for me. Checked in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: What changed? What's the important change that fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula. in hurry

```
<div class="header">
</div>
<div id="Content">
<div class="con"></div>
</div>
<div class="header">
</div>
```

css

```
html, body
{
height: 99%;
background-color:Black;
}
.header ,.footer
{
width: 960px;
height: 15%;
background-color:Gray;
}
#Content
{
min-height: 85%;
width: 960px;
background-color:Navy;
}
.con
{
min-height:900px;
width:960px;
background-color:Aqua;
}​
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gq6UQ/1/)

Comment: Can you show me this example in jsFiddle? I'm confused as to which is supposed to be the footer content.

Comment: @synedmohsin This idea works for me... but right now, I have some content that needs to be interactive with one another, expanding as the browser window gets bigger. In the HTML/CSS I have, how can I implement your example?

Comment: @synedmoshin After awhile, I figured out an answer using the following configurations. But, I found it easier to use your other answer below.

Answer (score 0):

http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

**HTML**

```
        <div class="wrapper">
            <p>http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/</p>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Copyright &copy; 2008</p>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em; /*!*/
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 4em; /*!*/
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution before, but didn't quite work for me. Is there a way in my code I should be implementing this? Can you show me in jFiddle?

Comment: You use too much of position:absolute.
Would be easier to me write everything again, than put you code together.

Comment: I can try rewriting it again. I didn't want to use too many divs to contain everything, which is why I did the `position: absolute;`

Answer (score -1):

Set the body to `height: 100%;` and `overflow: auto;`
Set the footer to `position: fixed;`, `bottom: 0;` and `left: 0;`

Then you must only set the margin-bottom of your content to the height of your footer.

Comment: This doesn't allow for the bottom footer to be seen when scrolled down to the bottom, which is what I want. Instead, it remains fixed to the very bottom of the browser window.

Answer (score -1):

Change the position of the footer from absolute to fixed:

```
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Whenever I do this, it doesn't set it to the bottom of the page. Instead, sets it to the very bottom of the window, which I don't want.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood the question then, sorry.

Comment: That's alright. :) I didn't clarify the issue enough on the top. Re-edited the initial post.