# How can I make the content area of my page expand to full height using the Bootstrap framework?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site that sometimes doesn't have much content in the main section of the page. The footer then slides way up. I would like to have a consistent minimum height on all the pages that keeps the footer roughly close to the bottom of the average page. Many of the examples that I have seen radically modify the CSS and that concerns me in relation to keeping the site responsive.

In my example on Bootply I want to have the lime green area expand to "fill" the page from the bottom of the nav area to the top of the footer.

[My Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/8Z3D16W2rH)

Comment: take a look here: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

Comment: I'm not really looking for a sticky footer but an expanding content area. The issue with the sticky footer code is that it relies on a specific height footer. The footer height in my example will change based on the viewport /device screen size.

Comment: Sticky footers also kinda break content when you have overflow, so I don't blame you there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with full height on screen, try surrounding your code with a class i.e `.fill` and set the class `.fill` to height: 100%

```
.fill { 
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: He asked for full height, not full width

Comment: sorry my bad. i didn't noticed well.

Answer (score 0):

Make `body,html{height:100%;}`. Put a class wrapper around the body content (not including footer) have a `.wrapper{ min-height: 100%; position:relative;}`. Finally add `.footer{position:absolute;}`

Here is the extended answer: 
[Make div stay at bottom of page's content all the time even when there are scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824831/make-div-stay-at-bottom-of-pages-content-all-the-time-even-when-there-are-scrol/8825714#8825714)

JSFiddle from the extended answer: http://jsfiddle.net/ELUGc/