# How to set footer to bottom of page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Footer at bottom of a page**

I created a responsive webpage in bootstrap3, i need to set footer on the bottom of the page, position fixed has some problem in desktop

Comment: Can youprovide your code ?

Comment: use `position: absolute;bottom:0;` if you not able to use `position: fix`

Comment: yes it worked thanks for the code

Answer (score 0):

use

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And **possible duplicate of** [Make div stay at bottom of page's content all the time even when there are scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824831/make-div-stay-at-bottom-of-pages-content-all-the-time-even-when-there-are-scrol/8825714#8825714)