# Make div stick to bottom of page

Tags: html, css

So I made a contact page and I want the footer `div` to be sticking to the bottom of the page not right after the contact form.

But if I put everything to a container `div` with `height:100%;` and make footer `bottom:0;` then the page will be "too long", you have to scroll, etc...

My `css` so far:

```
#footer{
    background-color:#fff;
    font:bold 14px;
    color:#1E88E5;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding:1%;
    border-top:1px solid #1E88E5;
}
```

Footer is just a normal full width `div` with some centered text atm.

Comment: Do you want the footer visible without needing the scroll?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Make div stay at bottom of page's content all the time even when there are scrollbars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824831/make-div-stay-at-bottom-of-pages-content-all-the-time-even-when-there-are-scrol)

Comment: i dont want it to be always at bottom visible,... i want it to stick to end of page, but in case the page gets "longer" you would scroll down and then see the footer

Answer (score 71):

You can probably use `position: fixed` to achieve this.

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

With this you will need to offset the bottom of the page so would suggest adding a `padding-bottom` to `.main` that is the height of the footer.

```
.main {
  padding-bottom: 30px /*whatever the height of your footer is*/
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Pritesh Gupta's solution](https://priteshgupta.com/2016/05/sticky-css-footer/) works really well for me:

I'm copy+pasting the code in case their site goes down:

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sticky Footer</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main>stuff</main>
    <footer>&copy; 2016</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 4rem);
}

footer {
  height: 4rem;
}
```

I don't know if it works in old browsers but I'm not so worried about that myself.

It also depends on you knowing the height of your footer, although it's worth pointing out that you don't necessarily have to set the height manually like in the code above since you can always figure out what it is if you know how much vertical padding and line-height the contents have...

Hope this helps, I spent most of the morning trying every single sticky footer tutorial on the web before stumbling across this technique and whilst [other](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) techniques do work this one requires minimal effort.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that easily with the `display: flex`.
You don't care about height `body` or `wrapper` tag.

**Example:** Please change the height of `main tag` any value if you want, `footer` always sticky to bottom(not `position: fixed`).

https://codepen.io/tronghiep92/pen/dzwRrO

**HTML markup**

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <header>my header</header>
   <main>main content, please change height</main>
  <footer>
    my footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

**CSS Solution**

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: auto; /* this is the solution */
}

main {
  height: 100px
}
```

**Or you can:**

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need sticky footer you can make it with 2 solutions.

**Solution 1:**

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    Content
</div>
<div class="footer">
    Sticky Footer
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html, .wrap{
  height:100%;
}

body > .wrap{
  height:auto;
  min-height:100%;
}

.wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100px; 
}

.footer{
  background:#662e8c;
  margin-top:-100px;
  height:100px;
  color:#fff;
  position:relative;
  line-height:180%;
  padding:0 10px;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ta1amejn/

---

**Solution 2 (With table properties):**

HTML:
    
        Content
    
    
        Footer

CSS:

```
body{
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}

html, body{
    height:100%;
}

.main{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    background:#eee;
    display:table-row;
}

.footer{
    /*height:30px;*/
    line-height:30px;
    width:100%;
    background:#00f0ad;
    display:table-row;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/zbtaoq1b/

---

If you want a fixed footer use this solution:

```
.footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```