# HTML footer/Div positioning

Tags: html, css, positioning, footer

Possibly a bit of a simple problem, but currently trying to create a personal website with a banner/header with the menu in, which works fine, and a footer bar. Both are using div's with a 'main' div in between for the main content. For some reason, the footer bar appears on top of the menu/header bar, covering it when I am trying to get it below the main section, and for it to stay at the bottom of the page.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "cicle-gordita";
  src: url("fonts/Cicle_Gordita.ttf") format("truetype");
  src: url("fonts/Cicle_Gordita.eot") format("opentype");
}
body {
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#banner {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #000000;
  /*background-image: url("images/menuHor.png");*/
}
.menuBit {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.menuContent:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menuContent {
  font-family: "cicle-gordita";
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.main {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  background: #ff0000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000000;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Personal - Home</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="banner">
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="menuBit">
        <h2 class="menuContent">HOME</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="menuBit">
        <h2 class="menuContent">BLOG</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="menuBit">
        <h2 class="menuContent">WORK</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='main'>
    <!-- Content Here -->
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

As shown in the head, I have a jscript/jquery file but all that contains is a small piece of code to fade the main in when the page loads, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue but you're setting the height of `.main` to `90%` while the others are fixed, I think the sum of heights should be `100%`

Comment: I'd suggest not using `position: fixed;` on both your body and your footer. Before diving deeper into this, please consider rethinking the foundation!

Comment: this isn't relative to the question but consider using html5's semantic elements for the header,footer,main

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make div stay at bottom of page's content all the time even when there are scrollbars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824831/make-div-stay-at-bottom-of-pages-content-all-the-time-even-when-there-are-scrol)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I don't agree :) the OP doesn't want the div to be fixed

Comment: @niceman Thanks for pointing out the sizes, wasn't quite thinking properly on that front and in terms of using the html5 elements, I would however they don't work on all versions of browsers, as some older browsers have difficulty with it

Comment: @TobyKing you can use html5shiv for that, also there are polyfills for html5's various apis in Modernizer's github wiki

Answer (score 2):

Add `bottom: 0;` to `#footer`

The default is `top: 0;`

Answer (score -2):

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;        
}
```

The position property when set on `fixed` will make the element stay in a fixed position no matter how you scroll, the position where it's "fixed" is determined by `top or bottom,left or right` properties.

If you want it to be positioned "normally" then remove the `position: fixed` property and you're set.

If you do want it to be fixed then you can follow Pat's answer.