# How to make links stay at the bottom of the page not screen

Tags: html, css

This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h30sdrxm/1/)

As you can see, the links are at `top:95%` of the screen not page., how to make it 95% of the page?

```css
.terms {
 position:absolute;
top:95%;
right:10px;
}

.terms a{
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 margin-left:10px;

}
```

```html
<h1>
Hello
</h1>
<p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p>


<div class="terms">
<a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
<a href="terms.html">Terms</a>
<a href="privacy.html">Privacy</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make div stay at bottom of page's content all the time even when there are scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824831/make-div-stay-at-bottom-of-pages-content-all-the-time-even-when-there-are-scrol)

Comment: No, in this question, it is fixed. I do not want it fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap a container around the elements and make it position:relative

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.terms {
  position: absolute;
  top: 95%;
  right: 10px;
}

.terms a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>
  <p>Hello again</p>


  <div class="terms">
    <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="terms.html">Terms</a>
    <a href="privacy.html">Privacy</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, Try this,
`position: relative;` `bottom: 0;` `float: right;`

```css
.terms {
    position:relative;
    bottom: 0;
    float: right;
}

.terms a{
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 margin-left:10px;

}
```

```html
<h1>
Hello
</h1>
<p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p>


<div class="terms">
<a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
<a href="terms.html">Terms</a>
<a href="privacy.html">Privacy</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `position:relative` to body.Or add a wrapper div and add `position:relative` to that div.

> For absolute position elements the top,bottom left,right values will be relative to the next parent element with relative(or absolute) positioning

```css
.wrapper{
  position:relative;
 }
 
 .terms {
     position:absolute;
       top:95%;
       right:10px;
    }

    .terms a{
     color:#333;
     text-decoration:none;
     margin-left:10px;

    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<h1>
    Hello
    </h1>
    <p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p>


    <div class="terms">
    <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="terms.html">Terms</a>
    <a href="privacy.html">Privacy</a>
    </div>
    
 </div>
```

For position  it at the bottom of the screen you can use `position:fixed;` This will  position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it when scrolled.

```css
.terms {
 position:fixed;
   top:94%;
   right:10px;
}

.terms a{
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 margin-left:10px;

}
```

```html
<h1>
Hello
</h1>
<p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p>


<div class="terms">
<a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
<a href="terms.html">Terms</a>
<a href="privacy.html">Privacy</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have positioned this element absolutely.

For it the 95% to mean anything that element needs to be related to something else. So 95% from the top of...what?

> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in the normal flow of elements in the document. In contrast, an element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes up no space when placing other elements. **The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor (non-static).** If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial container is used.
>
> <sup>[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position)</sup>

In this case, it's the `body` element.

So add

```
body {
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.terms {
  position: absolute;
  top: 95%;
  right: 10px;
}

.terms a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Hello
</h1>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>
<p>Hello again</p>


<div class="terms">
  <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
  <a href="terms.html">Terms</a>
  <a href="privacy.html">Privacy</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default **position : relative property assigned to html** tag means screen. So add **position:relative property to body tag .**

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
    .terms {
        position:absolute;
    top:95%;
    right:10px;
    }

    .terms a{
        color:#333;
        text-decoration:none;
        margin-left:10px;

    }
    </style>
    <h1>
    Hello
    </h1>
    <p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p>


    <footer style="float:right;">
    <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="terms.html">Terms</a>
    <a href="privacy.html">Privacy</a>
    </footer>
```

```
 <style>
    .terms {
        position:absolute;
    top:95%;
    right:10px;
    }

    .terms a{
        color:#333;
        text-decoration:none;
        margin-left:10px;

    }
    </style>
    <h1>
    Hello
    </h1>
    <p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p><p>Hello again</p>


    <footer style="float:right;">
    <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="terms.html">Terms</a>
    <a href="privacy.html">Privacy</a>
    </footer>
```