# div element not place in bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a page in our project.
I want div element with class attribute "site-info" put in bottom of page. I try {position:absolute;bottom:0} this element put in center of page. div with class called "modal-dialog" don't get height of page and div element called "site-info"
is in below this element but Appeared on center of page.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: The parent element of the element you are positioning absolutely, needs to have position relative. You can only absolutely position an element, `relative` to a parent. But I may be missing what you actually mean. See above comment!

Answer (score 0):

You can use css for this.

```
.site-info{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;}
```

There is a SO resource related to this... [Make div stay at bottom of page's content all the time even when there are scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824831/make-div-stay-at-bottom-of-pages-content-all-the-time-even-when-there-are-scrol)

Comment: thanks a lot. I dont want element fixed in bottom. only put in bottom of page and after scroll page see it.