# Can't align chat input to bottom of div in CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

I've tried everything I can think of, and it just won't work. Still a beginner, so please bear with me on this. It's a chat website, and I'm trying to align the input to the bottom of the chatbox. I've tried "float: bottom;", which is invalid. I've tried to vertically align it to the bottom like some posts I read suggested, but that wouldn't work either. I'm stumped, so help would be appriciated.

chat.view.tsx:

```
import { Message } from "./services/history.service";

export const ChatMessage = ({ username, text }: Message) => (
  <div>
    <b>{username}: </b>
    <span>{text}</span>
  </div>
);

export const ChatControlls = () => (
  <div float="bottom" className="message-box">
    <input placeholder="User" id="user-input" />
    <input placeholder="Message" id="message-input" />
  </div>
);

interface ChatProps {
  messages: Message[];
}

export const Chat = ({ messages }: ChatProps) => (
  <div className="chat">
    <div className="container">
      {messages.map((message, i) => (
        <ChatMessage key={i} {...message} />
      ))}
    </div>
    <ChatControlls />
  </div>
);
```

index.CSS:

```
  max-height: 1080px;
  min-height: 640px;
  max-width: 1920px;
  background-color: #daf4ff;

  border-radius: 1rem;
  border: 5px solid #444444;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.chat .container {
  overflow: overlay;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

input {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 1920px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  outline: 0;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.21428571em;
  font-family: Lato, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0.67857143em 1em;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  border-radius: 0.28571429rem;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

/* Message Box Crap */

.message-box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 125px 2fr 70px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.message-box input:first-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0 !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 0 !important;
  border-top-color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15);
}

/* button styling */
.btn {
  padding: 1em 2.1em 1.1em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  color: #fbdedb;
  background-color: #fbdedb;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #e74c3c;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0em -0.3rem 0em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0em -0.3rem 0em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  box-shadow: 0em -0.3rem 0em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  position: relative;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.btn:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
  -o-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
.btn.block {
  display: block !important;
}
.btn.circular {
  border-radius: 50em !important;
}

/* Colours */
.red {
  background-color: #d55050;
}
.teal {
  background-color: #50d5a1;
}
.sky {
  background-color: #6698cb;
}
.black {
  background-color: #5c6166;
}
.gray {
  color: black;
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
}
.orange {
  background-color: #e96633;
}
.pink {
  background-color: #cb99c5;
}
.green {
  background-color: #5bbd72;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #7abedf;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: #ecc92b;
}
.purple {
  background-color: #564f8a;
}

/* body style*/

body {
  background-color: #444444;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add some demo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I position my div at the bottom of its container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526035/how-can-i-position-my-div-at-the-bottom-of-its-container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood is you have to give a `position` `fixed` to your `message-box`.

Check this solution [Make div stay at bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824831/make-div-stay-at-bottom-of-pages-content-all-the-time-even-when-there-are-scrol)