# How to make a "footer" stick to the bottom of a facebox (jQuery plugin) dialog

Tags: jquery, css, facebox

I'm using a jQuery plugin called [Facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/) to create dialogs with content, and of course blocking and fading out the rest of the page.

This plugin can apply an external html page as a layout like this:

```
<a href="remote.html" rel="facebox">Open Facebox Dialog</a>
```

I plan on having the facebox dialog a fixed size, and the facebox will eventually have content that needs scrolling to access.

*However*, I also want some of the content to always be fixed to the bottom, like a "**fixed footer**".

I tried to apply [Joseph Silber's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8824859/1380710) (which would work if I wanted to do it for an entire page: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uw8f9/)), but it puts the fixed footer outside the dialog, on the bottom of the page:

[image: Screenshot of the footer being out of place]

I also tried applying [RegDwight's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2140776/1380710), which suggested something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/c82ha/2/

This makes it properly fixed to the bottom, but as the fiddle shows, it isn't shown before you scroll down to it.

I want it **fixed to the bottom, regardless of scrolling or size of the rest of the page**.

How can I do this?

---

Related:

- [Make div stay at bottom of page's content all the time even when there are scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824831/make-div-stay-at-bottom-of-pages-content-all-the-time-even-when-there-are-scrol)
- [CSS Push Div to bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140763/css-push-div-to-bottom-of-page)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to absolute position the footer inside the dialogue?

**HTML**

```html
<div class="dialogue">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.dialogue{
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
}
.dialogue .footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tz8cd/)