# Footer isn't at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I've got a big problem.

check this site: http://borbelykertlabor.hu/index.php

the footer is not at the very bottom of the page, if i try to apply:

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

it will work, but if there is a content big and there is a scrollbar, if you scroll something very bad will happen. :D

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140763/css-push-div-to-bottom-of-page/2140951#2140951

Answer (score 0):

Change your position:absolute to position:fixed

Comment: It is position: *fixed*;

Comment: Its good, yeah but for example look at this: http://borbelykertlabor.hu/content.php?page=gyermek&wrapp=12 I want it to be at the end of the content, not the bottom of the voiewport or how to say it :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS and the footer should stay at be visible at the bottom even when resized. Worked for me.

```
#footer{ 
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

#wrapperr{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ & I never have problems. Hope it will help you.